# Excessive file size

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an MS Access database which I use daily and continue to build upon.

This database from the time it has been created has grown from 2500 KB to about 8000 KB and is filled with forms (no queries) a few reports, and a lot of code written in VBA, DAO, and SQL.

In the past 24 hours the database grew from 8000 KB to 86000 KB. The only changes that I have made to it have been the addition of two new tables (with about 20 columns in each and 2000 rows of data) and have written a bunch of SQL routines (one of which links 4 tables and inserts records into the new tables).

I am still trying to understand where this excess memory was born. I have already compacted and repaired the database many times with no change to the result. Is it possible the SQL queries can inflate the file size? Your feedback will be greatly appreciated on how to go about researching these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Is it possible the SQL queries can inflate the file size?"*

A saved query (a `QueryDef` object) contains the text of the query's SQL statement.  Additionally the `QueryDef` contains information about other query properties.  However, the physical storage space required to hold that entire collection of information is relatively minor.

Although the saved queries do consume some space, I'm certain the new queries were not the reason your db file size increased ten-fold.

If you want to analyze file size contributors, start with the tables.  Create a new database and import all the tables from the old database.  Make sure to recreate all indexes and relationships.  Compact afterward.

The size of that new compacted db file will be a fair indication of the minimum space Access requires to hold your data.

Where you go from there depends on what you find.

As a side point, once you have the data moved into a separate database, consider keeping it there.  Then your original db can access the data with links to the tables in the back-end db file.  Such a split design is a widely-recommended practice, but for reasons other than file size.

Comment: Thanks. . I will consider your advice.. I am still confused however given that i really cant see where I added all that memory..